# Conic section: what is a "void conics"?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, conic-sections

I have to classify the following conic section:

$$x^2 - 2xy + y^2 + x - y + 1 = 0 $$

Through the analysis of the invariants, I found out it is a degenerate conics.

Now I know that if the conics is degenerate, I have many possibilities, but in this case det$(m) > 0$ where

$$m = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

In this case I know the conics is a degenerate ellipse, that is: a point.

Instead the professor said the conics is void.

In the options (in this exercise) there also was the option "a point", so I am asking you: why is this a void conics, and what is actually a void conics?

Thank you!

Comment: "Void" means void over the real numbers, i.e., no real solution ($z^2+z+1=0$, see below). Over the complex numbers this is not "void".

Comment: Suppose I have a conics which turns out to be an imaginary ellipse: if there were four options like $A$: real ellipse; $B$: parabola; $C$: void; $D$: a couple of parallel lines, then the correct answer would be $C$?

Comment: You mean, imaginary ellipse like in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4431864/demonstration-of-an-imaginary-ellipse)? There is a wikipedia link with details.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes

Comment: This determinant is zero

Comment: @Empy2 Wow, I'm so sleepy haha. That makes sense. Two imaginary lines then, which is considered as void in the real plane.

Comment: "Conics" is a plural word; the singular is "conic" or "conic section".

Answer (score 6):

You can rewrite the quadric as
$$(x-y)^2+(x-y)+1=0$$
Now define $z:=x-y$ so that this becomes
$$z^2+z+1=0$$
which is a quadratic equation with $\Delta=-3<0$ thus the solution set is empty, i.e. the conic is void.

Comment: Oh this would mean a couple of imaginary lines! Indeed void, because we are considering solution in the real plane. I miscalculated the small determinant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to classify conics, at least to me, involves using a $3×3$ matrix $M$ involving all the coefficients, and its principal minors (meaning the minors of the $(k,k)$ elements, here labeled $m_k$).

Given the conic

$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$

the associated $M$ matrix will take the form

$\begin{pmatrix}2A&B&D\\B&2C&E\\D&E&2F\end{pmatrix},$

where I multiply elements by $2$ to clear fractions. Then, apart from this clearing factor, your $2×2$ matrix is $m_3$.

We then have the following algorithm (circles are deemed ellipses with coincident foci):

If $\det m_3>0$:

- If $\det M$ has the same sign as $A$ or $C$, conic is void (does not appear in real coordinates).
- If $\det M$ is zero, the conic is a point (which is the center of the ellipse that would exist in the next case).
- If $\det M$ has the opposite sign from $A$ or $C$, conic is an ellipse.

If $\det m_3=0:$

- If $\det M$ is nonzero, conic is a parabola; reversing the sign corresponds to reversing the orientation of this parabola.
- If $\det M$ is zero, then compute either $\det m_1$ or $\det m_2$ (both will have the same sign). A negative value gives two parallel lines; zero gives a single line; a positive value gives a void (no figure in the real plane).

If $\det m_3<0$:

- If $\det M$ is zero, conic is two intersecting lines; otherwise it is a hyperbola.
- This case never produces a void conic.

We apply this algorithm to the equation

$x^2-2xy+y^2+x-y+1=0.$

$M=\begin{pmatrix}2&-2&1\\-2&2&-1\\1&-1&2\end{pmatrix}.$

The $(3,3)$ minor determinant ($m_3$) gives zero, corresponding to a parabola or its degenerated parallel lines (second set of possibilities above). Then $\det M=0$, meaning the degenerate case; so we have to check either of the other two principal minors. This gives $\det m_1=3$ or $\det m_2=3$, thus positive; therefore the proposed parallel lines disappear out of the real plane.